# Check if youtube api player is paused

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have created a button that pauses and plays a youtube video on click. I am trying to check if the video is already paused if so play, if its playing then pause. isPaused is not a function. What is the function I am looking for?

```
document.getElementById("playButton").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if(!!player.isPaused()){
        player.playVideo();
    } 
    else {
        player.pauseVideo();
    }
});
```

Comment: https://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/to-check-youtube-video-state-in-javascript/ This may be useful

Comment: Thanks @Tim Ihave tried this but with no luck: if(!!YT.PlayerState.PAUSED()){

Comment: @Tim I tried this too but with no luck    

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.playing) {
              var stop = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-play');
              stop[0].click();
        }
        else{    // If video – pause
            var start = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-pause');
            start[0].click();
        }
      }

Comment: Not sure then, hopefully someone will see this and be able to help you more.

Comment: The [`onStateChange`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#Events) event should be what you're looking for. Check out the [sample HTML](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) for a sample implementation.

Comment: @user10629012 can you provide more details?, please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

Without mode details about your HTML controls, I think you're using a HTML element for control the reproduction *(play)* and pause functionality of a video.

If so, in the `onPlayerStateChange` function, you have to set the logic as follows:

```
// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

  // If the video is PLAYING, set the onclick element for pause the video.
  // Once the "playButton" is clicked, the video will be paused.
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    document.getElementById('playButton').innerHTML = 'Pause';

    // Set the onclick event to the button for pause the YouTube video.
    document.getElementById('playButton').onclick = function() {
      player.pauseVideo();
    };
  }

  // If the video is PAUSED, set the onclick element for pause the video.
  // Once the "playButton" is clicked, the video will resume the video = continue playing the video.
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
    document.getElementById('playButton').innerHTML = 'Play';
    document.getElementById('playButton').onclick = function() {
      player.playVideo();
    };
  }
}
```

This function was modified from the available sample code in the [YouTube Player API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Getting_Started).

Here is a [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/xujn3pgc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, you should use the `player.getPlayerState()` function of the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status), it returns the playback status of the player as:

- -1 – unstarted
- 0 – ended
- 1 – playing
- 2 – paused
- 3 – buffering
- 5 – video cued

So, your code should be updated as:

```
document.getElementById("playButton").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if(player.getPlayerState()==1){ //Returns true if video is playing
      player.pauseVideo();
    }else{
      player.playVideo(); 
    }
});
```